# Is the following equality true? : $\log\left(-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^3\right)=3\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$

Tags: logarithms

Is the equality below true over all complex numbers? $$\log\left(\frac{1+\frac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}}{1-\frac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}}\right)=3\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

The L.H.S. (Left hand side expression) simplifies to $\log\left(-\frac{(x+1)^3}{(x-1)^3}\right)=\log\left(-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^3\right)$

But I think you cannot take the exponent $3$ outside the $\log$ because of that negative sign; if you are allowed to, then yes, the $(x-1)$ becomes $(1-x)$ as desired, but I want to confirm.

**So essentially, is the below equality true?**
$$\log\left(-\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^3\right)=3\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

Comment: When these are defined, yes, since $\log(u^3)=3\log(u)$ for every real $u>0$.

Comment: No... It's in the form of $-(u)^3$; I'm asking whether $\log(-(u)^3) = 3\log(-u)$. It's not $\log((-u)^3)$, it's $\log(-(u)^3)$ which is being discussed here...

Comment: Sorry but $(-u)^3=-(u)^3$ hence it seems that $\log((-u)^3)=\log(-(u^3))=3\log(-u)$ is rock solid when $-u$ is positive real (as my first comment says).

Comment: Ah.. you mentioned that it's for only positive Real numbers. Not for negative then?

Comment: Kugelblitz: To silently replace the crucial `real` by `complex` in the question is, frankly speaking, bad manners. -1.

Comment: No; I realized I needed an answer for x belonging to complex numbers...

Comment: "No" to what? You did not replace the crucial `real` by `complex` without notice? Although the point was discussed in answers (and explicitely mentioned in the comments above)?

Comment: Note also that, after you experienced the revelation that complex numbers were actually involved, you should have added to the question some explanations about the log you wish to consider.

Comment: I meant 'No' as in 'I didn't mean to do it intentionally'; my bad.

Comment: Put modulus on right side

Answer (score 2):

$$\log(-a^3)=\log((-a)^3)=3\log(-a).$$

In complex numbers, the property doesn't necessarily hold because of the indeterminacy of the imaginary part. For instance, with real $a>0$ and choosing the principal branch

$$\log(-a^3)=\log(|a|^3)+i\pi\ne3\log(-a)=3(\log(|a|)+i\pi).$$

Comment: this is not true, it must be $-a^3>0$

Comment: Mh, $a$ is complex.